# How not to store a value in a column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've got me this nice table.

```
create table Records (
  Id uniqueidentifier primary key,
  Occasion datetime not null,
  Information varchar(999) default ' '
)
```

When I execute the first line line below, I get an error. When I execute the second, I see *NULL* in the cell. How should I insert stuff into the table so that the default white space kicks in?

```
insert into Records values (newid(), convert(varchar(21), getdate(), 121))
insert into Records values (newid(), convert(varchar(21), getdate(), 121), null)
```

The error message is the defaulty one but I'll put it in here anyway, in case someone asks.

> Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.

Comment: try specifying the column names you're inserting. For example: `insert into Records(Id, Occasion)` and see if it helps

Comment: Firstly, add a column list after your insert to explicitly define the columns you are inserting into. Secondly, don't cast `GETDATE()` to a varchar as you are putting into a datetime column. Try that and come back

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using the `DEFAULT` keyword:

```
INSERT INTO Records VALUES (newid(), CONVERT(varchar(21), getdate(), 121), DEFAULT)
```

Or, better, by specifying the exact columns with the `INSERT` statement

```
INSERT INTO Records (Id, Occasion) 
VALUES (newid(), CONVERT(varchar(21), getdate(), 121))
```

Or:

```
INSERT INTO Records (Id, Occasion, Information) 
VALUES (newid(), CONVERT(varchar(21), getdate(), 121), DEFAULT)
```

Why is it better?

1. Because you shouldn't rely on the order of columns in your table.
2. Because you shouldn't rely on the fact that the table will never have any new or removed columns (which is when your query will break again).

Also interesting: [SQL Column definition : default value and not null redundant?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11862188/sql-column-definition-default-value-and-not-null-redundant)

Comment: Very nice answer. To the point and with both samples and alternatives. +1 definitely. However, I'm unclear why it's better to use named parameters instead of *default* keyword. Is it my C#ness spooking?

Comment: I'll edit the answer. The problem is not `DEFAULT`, but the lack of explicit columns in the `INTO` clause.

Comment: Oh, that's a great explanation. I'd bounty you if I wasn't a cheap bastard and rep junkie, hehe. Once I've passed 10k, I'll start doing that, though. But first, I need to get into 5-digit rep.

Comment: @KonradViltersten: We'll meet again. You can bounty me on another answer, in the future ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
insert into Records (
  Id 
  Occasion 
)
values (newid(), convert(varchar(21), getdate()), 121))
```

Try this.

when you don't specify column names in insert query, sql-server expects values for all the columns. that is why your first query is throwing error as you have supplied value for two columns only, whereas your second query is running correctly

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
insert into Records values (newid(), convert(varchar(21), getdate()), 121)
```

You have to close the `(` of convert.

Comment: You misplaced the third parameter of convert() function (121).

Comment: Aah k. Didnt think of that. Thanks.

Comment: Downvoting because this totally changes the intention (the Information column will have 121 inserted) and misses the actual reason the poster was getting errors.