# Date field not retrieved using JPA

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I have table in mysql data base that called course that has the following columns :

- List item
- id - int primary key auto increment
- name - varchar(250)
- start_date - timestamp default now()

And I have the following entity defined :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "course")
public class Course {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
private String name;
@Column(name = "start_date")
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date startDate;

protected Course() {

}

public Course(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public Date getStartDate() {
    return startDate;
 }
```

}

So the database should populate the date column. 
I use Spring data JPA so my dao looks like this:

```
public interface CourseRepository extends CrudRepository<Course, Long> {
```

}

I create a new Course entity (via the above constructor that accepts name):

```
courseRepository.save(new Course("Algebra"));
```

and save it to table it seems that the id columns is auto increment but the date column is null, even though it defined as default now.

Comment: It seem you define default in your database not your entity. So when it generate sql like "date=null" from the entity, does your database will accept or modify the value? I believe it will accept null as your result

Comment: Deafult doesn't mean not null.. here spring is creating a full query with specifically saying db to set null in that field. ...for more details please go though: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11862188/sql-column-definition-default-value-and-not-null-redundant

Answer (score 2):

Your `start_date` is a timestamp but you are using `Date` in your model.

Change

```
@Column(name = "start_date")
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date startDate;
```

to

```
@Column(name = "start_date", nullable = false, updatable = false)
@CreationTimestamp
private Timestamp startDate; //import java.sql.Timestamp;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer below example

```
@Column(name = "created_date")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/YYYY")
private Date createdDate;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you never set `startDate`. Change your `Course` class constructor like following:

```
public Course(String name, Date startDate) {
    this.name = name;
    this.startDate = startDate;
}
```

And call `save()` like following:

```
courseRepository.save(new Course("Algebra", new Date()));
```

The save method get the current date of your system and save this into database.